# How do I display all members in the member collection, using find in mongoose

Tags: angularjs, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I have an application built using the MEAN Stack, I am able to display one record at a time when using this method:

in my member model I have:

```
module.exports.getMemberByRFID = function(rfidkey, callback){
const query = {rfidkey: rfidkey}
Member.findOne(query, callback);
}
```

In my routes file I have:

```
// Authenticate Member
router.post('/authenticatemember', (req, res, next) => {
const rfidkey = req.body.rfidkey;

Member.getMemberByRFID(rfidkey, (err, member) => {
    if(err) throw err;
    if(member){
        const token = jwt.sign(member, config.secret, {
                expiresIn: 50 //1 week
            });

            res.json({
                success: true,
                token: 'JWT2 '+token,
                member: {
                    id: member._id,
                    firstname: member.firstname,
                    surname: member.surname,
                    email: member.email,
                    expirydate: member.expirydate
                }
            });
        } else {
            return res.json({success: false, msg: 'member not found'});
        }
        })
});
```

In my AuthService.ts file I have:

```
 authenticateMember(member){
let headers = new Headers();
headers.append('Content-Type', 'application/json');
return this.http.post('http://localhost:3000/users/authenticatemember', member,{headers: headers})  
  .map(res => res.json());
```

}

And then in my angular TS file upfront I have:

```
onSearchSubmit(){
    var inputElement = <HTMLInputElement>document.getElementById('rfidkey');
    const member = {
        rfidkey: inputElement.value
    }
    this.authService.authenticateMember(member).subscribe(data => {
        if(data.success){
            this.authService.storeMemberData(data.token, data.member)
                console.log(data.member);

                var newexpiry = new Date(data.member.expirydate);
                var today = new Date();

                if (today > newexpiry) {
                    this.flashMessage.show('member has expired', {
                cssClass: 'alert-danger', 
                timeout: 5000});
                } else {
                    this.flashMessage.show('member is active', {
                cssClass: 'alert-success', 
                timeout: 5000});
                }



                var n = newexpiry.toString();

                var inputElement = <HTMLInputElement>document.getElementById('firstname');
                    inputElement.value = data.member.firstname;
                var inputElement = <HTMLInputElement>document.getElementById('surname');
                    inputElement.value = data.member.surname;
                var inputElement = <HTMLInputElement>document.getElementById('email');
                    inputElement.value = data.member.email;
                var inputElement = <HTMLInputElement>document.getElementById('expirydate');
                    inputElement.value = n;



        //  this.router.navigate(['searchmember']);
        } else {
            this.flashMessage.show(data.msg, {
                cssClass: 'alert-danger', 
                timeout: 5000});
            var inputElement = <HTMLInputElement>document.getElementById('firstname');
                    inputElement.value = "";
                var inputElement = <HTMLInputElement>document.getElementById('surname');
                    inputElement.value = "";
                var inputElement = <HTMLInputElement>document.getElementById('email');
                    inputElement.value = "";
                var inputElement = 
<HTMLInputElement>document.getElementById('expirydate');
                    inputElement.value = "";
            this.router.navigate(['/searchmember']);
        }
    });

}
```

This gives me the following result:
[Searching for a single record](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uqlNO.png)

Now what I want to do is have a page named Display All Members, and display all records in a datatable which can be searched and sorted.

Does anyone know how I can find ALL records with mongoose and send the list of all members to the front end Angular 2 application and place them in to the table?

thanks!

Comment: Which part are you stuck on? Finding all of the data with Mongoose, or requesting the data from your app, or displaying the data in the table, or everything?

Comment: at the moment, everything. I am new to this way of coding, usually use SQL but have had to switch over to the MEAN stack for an assignment

Comment: Honestly I would try searching for similar questions about each of the parts you're having trouble with, if you haven't been given any material to help complete your assignment. At the moment, this isn't really a fit for SO because it's a really specific solution to your assignment which comprises a number of parts which do have documented solutions here and elsewhere. If you're stuck with one specific task and have tried solving it yourself, search some more and then I would ask another question. Good luck!

Comment: Ok thanks for your time!